# Can't connect to server hosted on another computer on the same network

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-tekkit

I recently bought a new gaming computer. For a while I've played Tekkit with a friend, hosting the server on my laptop. Now I want to play Tekkit on the new computer, but in order to have high graphics and a good FPS, I'm continuing to host the server on my laptop. However, when I tried to connect to the server with my new PC, I got the error message "Connection timeout. Failed to connect: Connect". I tried both localhost and my router's public IP address, but both produced the same result. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the server is hosted on a different computer, you cannot use `localhost` to connect to the server on your laptop from your new pc. `localhost` is only for server host on the same computer.

To connect to your server host on the laptop from a different pc, you should first find out the local ip address of your laptop.

You can check your local ip address of your laptop by browsing this website from your laptop:   "[What is my Local IP address?](http://www.whatismybrowser.com/what-is-my-local-ip-address)" or check it manually using cmd from your laptop ([How To Check Your Local IP](http://www.helpfulpctools.com/HowToCheckYourLocalIP.php)). The local ip address maybe like : `192.168.0.100`

Now you can connect to the server using the local ip of your laptop from your new pc.
If you want to use your public ip, you have to set your laptop as DMZ host , Virtual Server or forward port to your laptop. This has to be set at your router.